# How can I reduce whitespace between ordered list items?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting unwanted top margin space

I've tried to remove the ul which defeats the li I need before the ol resulting in no li circle.only the unwanted space above the start of the circle and the number 1 and the text.

I used this too:

```
.collapsible {background-color: #353D30;color:#CCC;text-shadow: 0px 0px yellow;cursor: pointer;padding: 1px;width: 100%;border: none;
  text-align: left;outline: none;font-size: 17px;font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", "serif";top:0px;left:0px;letter-spacing: 1px;font-weight:500;z index: 234;
  min-height:1px;}.active, .collapsible:hover { background-color: #063;}
.content { padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px; display: none; overflow: hidden;background-color:  #353D30; top:0px; left:0px; min-height:1px;    
  z index: 234;}.collapsible:after { content: '\002B'; color: #FF0;  font-weight: 500;  float: left;  margin-left: 10px;}.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
```

I have other collapsibles that don't have that unwanted space and are working 100%. It's only happening when I added the ul and li in front of the ol

```
<button class="collapsible">Authority of the Board of Directors</button>
<div class="content"><summary><ul><li><ol><li><h2>"This"</h2></li><ul type="a">
<li><h2>"manage"</h2></li><li><h2>"consider"</h2></li><li><h2>"conduct"</h2></li>
<li><h2>"determine"</h2></li><li><h2>"proceed"</h2></li>
<li><h2>"appoint"</h2></li></ul><li><h2>"The "</h2></li><li><h2>"The "</h2></li>
<li><h2>"This"</h2></li></ol></li></ul>  
</summary></div>
```

Comment: Please post a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can help you out.

Comment: i do not completely understand your question, could you probably add a snippet for better understanding?

Comment: please add html along with css

Comment: ok added all i can

Comment: There are tools in the editor to let you present your code in a suitable manner. Please use them. Also, it's more clear if you refer to your elements using words rather than tag abbreviations.

Comment: @GarethHards, i think some part of css is missing at last while pasting

Comment: Its a great collapsible thats functioning great, the contents of it, can i change it and not affect the others? can i style the collapsible button <button class="collapsible">Authority of the Board of Directors</button>
<div class="content">   please can someone show me how?

Comment: Please, post a readable question, ident your code.

Comment: does it perhaps have something to do with how deep the collapsible is within other collapsibles?

Answer (score -1):

Just a example, you can use `padding-top: 20px;` to your element class read more at [css padding](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)

please also post your code, because I can see it with more details.

why not simple change your the html to this ?

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
 #textblock27 {
   text-shadow: 0px 0px #FF0;
   font-size: 17px;
   color:#000;
   font-weight:500;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 background:#9F0;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
  border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px 1px 1px 1px;
 border-color:#353D30;
 text-align:left;
 font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", "serif";  
} 
 .collapsible {
  background-color: #353D30;
color:#CCC;
text-shadow: 0px 0px yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", "serif";
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight:500;
  z index: 234;
  min-height:1px;
  
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #063;
}

.content {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:  #353D30;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  min-height:1px; 
  z index: 234;
}
.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #FF0;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}


summary {
 background-color:white;
 width:100%;
 text-align:left;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
  }
</style>
<button class="collapsible">Authority of the Board of Directors</button>
<div class="content"><summary>
<p id="textblock27"style="color:yellow; background-color: white ; font-size:16.5px; border-style:solid;
 border-width:5px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-color:#CCC;"></></p>
 <ul><li><ol><li><h2>"This"</h2></li><ul type="a">
<li><h2>"manage"</h2></li><li><h2>"consider"</h2></li><li><h2>"conduct"</h2></li>
<li><h2>"determine"</h2></li><li><h2>"proceed"</h2></li>
<li><h2>"appoint"</h2></li></ul><li><h2>"The "</h2></li><li><h2>"The "</h2></li>
<li><h2>"This"</h2></li></ol></li></ul> 
<p id="textblock27"style="color:yellow; background-color: white ; font-size:16.5px; border-style:solid;
 border-width:5px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-color:#CCC;"></></p>
</summary></div>
<button class="collapsible">Indemnification of Directors</button>
<div class="content">
<summary>
<p id="textblock27"style="color:yellow; background-color: white ; font-size:16.5px; border-style:solid;
 border-width:5px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-color:#CCC;"></></p>
<ul>
<li><h2>"This Memorandum "</h2></li>
<ul type="a">
<li><h2>"advance"</h2></li>
<li><h2>"indemnify"</h2></li>
<li><h2>"purchase"</h2></li>
</ul></ul>
<p id="textblock27"style="color:yellow; background-color: white ; font-size:16.5px; border-style:solid;
 border-width:0px 0px 5px 0px;
 border-color:#CCC;"></></p>
</summary></div>
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an odd answer to a question asking how to remove "unwanted top margin space". If you don't have enough information for a complete answer, with an explanation of how the answer answers the question, it might be better to not post an answer at all... See [answer].

Comment: He did't posted the code when I answer I will edit the answer now

Comment: using padding will be difficult to add it my div holding my lists, but if i can add it individually to the specific collapsible that would be awesome ,, how do i do that ? here is the  code for the collapsible. :<button class="collapsible">Authority of the Board of Directors</button>
<div class="content">

Comment: answer updated , please check and see if this is what you need

Comment: #textblock27a {
   
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family: Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", "serif"; 
 }

Comment: Ive added everything as it is in my coding in your preview it looks great, in mine it looks like the text is lower in the first line

Comment: thank you i think the code is great and is fine and is perhaps because of a combination of other coding in mine that ill read over.